# How to store value of chdir in a variable?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Using windows command, I want to store output of `chdir` command in a variable. I tried it like following, but it's storing text `chdir` in variable rather than it's actual value:

```
set currentDirectory=chdir
```

Can you please help how I can achieve this?

Comment: You don't have any output for the chdir command. What about set currentDirectory = chdir C:\reports

Comment: Do you search for `set currentDirectory=%CD%` ?

Comment: It does. If you open command prompt and hit `chdir`, it'll show your current directory.

Comment: Thanks jeb!!! It worked! If you had answered, I would have accepted it. Still upvoting your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory can be accessed by the pseudo variables `%CD%` and `%__CD%__%`.

The difference is that `%__CD__%` also appends a backslash to all directories, `%CD%` only for the root directory.